Webhook fails if function with phpmailer is included
I have a webhook that makes a http request with some parameters which will update the database in the called URL after it is called. If I have the savePayment() function on its own it is fine but as soon as I add the completeTestBooking() function it fails.
I have manually entered the URL with all the same parameters there are no errors; neither the webhook nor the called URL log any errors.
Part of my webhook:
try {
    $payload = json_decode($input);
    if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        throw new Exception('JSON decode error: ' . json_last_error_msg());
    }
    
    file_put_contents('webhook.log', print_r($payload, true), FILE_APPEND); // Log payload

    if ($payload->eventType === 'PaymentSession.captured' || $payload->eventType === 'PaymentSession.approved') {
        if (isset($payload->data->metadata->site)) {
            $intent = $payload->data->id;
            $site = $payload->data->metadata->site;
            $oid = $payload->data->metadata->oid;

            $endpoint = "https://".$site."/complete";
            $params = array('pid' => $intent, 'oid' => $oid, 'u' => '1');
            $url = $endpoint . '?' . http_build_query($params);

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            if (curl_errno($ch)) {
                throw new Exception('cURL error: ' . curl_error($ch));
            }
            file_put_contents('curlResult.log', print_r($result, true), FILE_APPEND); 
            curl_close($ch);

            echo $url;
        } else {
            echo "Metadata does not contain 'site' key.";
        }
    } elseif ($payload->eventType === 'Customer.created') {
        file_put_contents('webhookcustomer.log', print_r($payload, true), FILE_APPEND);  
    } else {
        echo "Event type is not supported.";
    }

    http_response_code(200);
    echo "Webhook received and verified successfully.";
}

My complete.php:
if(isset($_GET['u']))
{
    $row = $db->selectRow(
        'SELECT data FROM meta_data WHERE meta_id = ?
        ',
        [$_GET['oid']]
    );

    $jsonBookingDetails = $row['data'];
    $jsonBookingDetails = json_decode($jsonBookingDetails);
    
    if ($jsonBookingDetails->type === "test") {
        // webhook is 400 if completeTestBooking() is omitted
        completeTestBooking("1234",$db);

        savePayment($jsonBookingDetails->name, $address, $jsonBookingDetails->amount, $_GET['pid'], "Succeeded", $db);
    }
}

function completeTestBooking($testId, $db)
{
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    try {
        //Server settings
        $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
        $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_OFF;                     
        $mail->isSMTP();                                            
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.example.com';
        $mail->Port = 465;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
        $mail->Username = 'info@co.uk';
        $mail->Password = 'password';

        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('info@co.uk', 'Bookings');
        $mail->addAddress('test@example.com');     

        //Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
        $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
        $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

        $mail->send();
            return true;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
            return false;
    }   
}

I have gone directly with the generated URL without issues.

Sounds like completeTestBooking() is getting an error. Without knowing what that does, it's impossible to say why.

$endpoint is missing .php in the URL. Is there a rewrite rule that adds this?

So the bizarre thing is if I go directly there are no errors, also the webhook seems to reach that function because I get the emails, it just never reaches 200. I have added the function.

$mail = new PHPMailer(true); should be inside try.

Yes it does rewrite without the extension, if I comment out the completeTestBooking() it reaches the 200.

If you're getting the emails then obviously the function is running, and I can't see any way that could prevent savePayment() from running.

When you get the 400 error, what does your PHP error log say?

Sorry my mistake I meant it sends http_response_code(200); to the event. Not error 400.

Still, check the PHP error log to see what happens when there's no 200.

There is no question in this post. PS Please: Clarify via edits, not comments. Delete & flag obsolete comments. Avoid social & meta commentary in posts.

Looks to be swallowing exception

Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st point in execution where behaviour or a variable is not you expect, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.
